# Why do I get the error: "500 Internal Server Error" when passing parameters using Ajax on Wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a dynamic contact form on my Wordspress webpage.

This is the HTML structure:

```
        <div class="form_content">
            <div> Name:    <span> <input type="text" id="fullname"> </span></div>
            <div> E-mail:  <span> <input type="text" id="email">    </span></div>
            <div> Message: <span> <input type="text" id="text">     </span></div>
            <div id="sendBtn"> Submit </div>
        </div>
```

I have the functions that grabs the inputs from the HTML and sends them to a content.php file I have on my twentyfifteen-child theme.

```
// Send button for the "contact form".
jQuery('#sendBtn').click(function(){
    //get info 
    var fullname = jQuery("#fullname").val();
    var email = jQuery("#email").val();
    var text = jQuery("#text").val();
    //send info to php 
    jQuery.ajax({
        beforeSend: function() {
            if ( IsEmail(email) == false) {
                jQuery('#aboutUnsuccess').show("slow");
                /*jQuery('#pixel-thing').show("fast");*/
                jQuery('.form_content').hide("slow");
            }
        },
        url: 'http://54.149.xx.xx/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen-child/contact.php', 
        type: "POST", 
        data: ({ "fullname": fullname, "email": email, "text": text }), 
        success: function (results){
            if ( IsEmail(email) == true) {
                //hide table 
                jQuery('.form_content').hide('slow', function() {
                    jQuery('.form_content').hide( "slow" );
                  });
                //show textboxes
                jQuery('#aboutSuccess').show("slow");
                jQuery( "#aboutSuccess" ).append( "<iframe id=\"pixel-thing\" src=\"http://54.149.xx.xx/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen-child/thePixel.html\" width=\"1\" height=\"1\"  border=\"0\"></iframe>" );

            /************************************/
                window.google_trackConversion({
                  google_conversion_id: 666, 
                  google_remarketing_only: true
                });

            /*************************************/
            }
        }
    });
```

and finally my content.php handles the parameters and sends the relevant information to my email:

```
<?php 
require_once "Mail.php";

        if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

            $email = $_POST['email'];       
            $email_to = "info@example.com";

            $host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465";
            $username = 'myEmail@email.com';
            $password = 'passpaspaspas';

            $email_subject = "You have a new email from $email via example.com website";
            $message = $_POST['text']; 

            $headers = array ('From' => $email, 'To' => $email_to,'Subject' => $email_subject);
            $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
              array ('host' => $host,
                'auth' => true,
                'username' => $username,
                'password' => $password));

            $mail = $smtp->send($email_to, $headers, $message);

            if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
              echo($mail->getMessage());
            } else {
              echo("Message successfully sent!\n");
            }
        }
```

I am moving my website which was built without any MVC/CMS, to wordpress. This works fine with my "regular" website.

Why my code isn't working within wordpress?

This is the output from Chromes "Network":

```
Remote Address:54.159.xx.xx:80
Request URL:http://54.159.xx.xx/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen-child/contact.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:63
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:wp-settings-1=editor%3Dtinymce%26posts_list_mode%3Dlist; wp-settings-time-1=1424359234
Host:54.149.xx.xx
Origin:http://54.149.xx.xx
Referer:http://54.149.xx.xx/?page_id=73
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
fullname: Test
email:Test@gmail.com
text:This is a test 
Response Headersview source
Connection:close
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Tue, 24 Feb 2015 14:13:46 GMT
Server:Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress doesn't like you directly posting to a php file within a theme. What you should be doing is post to / (or any template/path you would like to post to, say "contact") and place the form handling code in your theme files.

I'd suggest putting your code in functions.php, and adding an action to listen for the ajax request, see [wp_ajax_(action) in the Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)) for a detailed description.

-- edit --

If you want to get going quickly (don't we all) this code snippet does almost everything you want, place it in `functions.php` and call `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` from your javascript. In the ajax-call make sure you add a variable `action` and fill it with `my_action` for this example to work.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );

function my_action_callback() {
    $data['output'] = $_REQUEST['username'];
    echo json_encode($data);
    wp_die();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention Eric :) 
Let me dig in to it for a while.. :D

Comment: Since I'm not so familiar with Wordpress, I'll sit myself tomorrow and read how to build a plugin since I don't have any clue of what's going on in the link you sent, either way, I'll have to learn doing this right. 

Just a little question before, I moved the content of "contact.php" to a function. What do I write in my .js file instead of this line:  `url: 'http://54.149.xx.xx/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen-child/contact.php', 
`?

Comment: I can imagine, the learning curve can be steep sometimes :)

You have to use `admin-ajax.php`, but it would be even better to use ajax_object.ajax_url as you can dynamically set the correct URL in Wordpress. This link is a little more detailed to get you going: http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: I have this link saved for tomorrow too :) 
Thanks!

Comment: And I've just edited my answer to get you up and running real' quick ;)

Comment: Ok, I explored the issue, but now I'm facing a new problem. 
I cant use "beforesend" using $.post!

Comment: OH, So I can use $.ajax.. Where do I write the action?

Comment: OK: `data: ({ "action": "submit_contact_form", "fullname": fullname, "email": email, "text": text }),`

now I get errors in my console: 

`POST http://54.149.xx.xx/wp_admin/admin_ajax.php 404 (Not Found)jquery.js?ver=1.11.1:4 m.ajaxTransport.sendjquery.js?ver=1.11.1:4 m.extend.ajaxmain.js:66 (anonymous function)jquery.js?ver=1.11.1:3 m.event.dispatchjquery.js?ver=1.11.1:3 m.event.add.r.handle `

Comment: You're using wp_admin, not wp-admin.

Comment: Yes. Thanks, I found the problem, You helped me a lot! Thank you for giving me a head-start on working with plugins! :D I got some new problems on the way.. If you have free time to help me I'll be happy :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28747354/why-do-i-get-post-http-54-xx-xx-xx-wp-admin-admin-ajax-php-500-internal-serv